# How to add a tooltip on mouseover of each slice of a pie chart using canvas

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, canvas

```js
    var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
    var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
    var cw = canvas.width;
    var ch = canvas.height;
    ctx.lineWidth = 2;
    ctx.font = '14px verdana';

    var PI2 = Math.PI * 2;
    var myColor = ["Green", "Red", "Blue"];
    var myData = [30, 15, 38, 22, 30, 20, 10];
    var cx = 150;
    var cy = 150;
    var radius = 100;

    ctx.globalAlpha = 0.50;
    pieChart(myData, myColor);
    ctx.globalAlpha = 1.00;

    function pieChart(data, colors) {
    // calc data total
    var total = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        total += data[i];
    }
    // calc sweep angles for each piece of pie
    var sweeps = []
    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        sweeps.push(data[i] / total * PI2);
    }
    // draw outer pie
    var accumAngle = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < sweeps.length; i++) {
        var f = randomColor();
        drawWedge(radius, accumAngle, accumAngle + sweeps[i], f, data[i]);
        accumAngle += sweeps[i];
    }
 
    }

    function drawWedge(radius, startAngle, endAngle, fill, label) {
    // draw the wedge
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(cx, cy);
    ctx.arc(cx, cy, radius, startAngle, endAngle, false);
    ctx.closePath();
    ctx.fillStyle = fill;
    ctx.strokeStyle = 'white';
    ctx.fill();
    ctx.stroke();
    }

    function randomColor() {
    return ('#' + (Math.floor(Math.random() * 0x1000000) + 
    0x1000000).toString(16).substr(1));
    }
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width=512 height=512></canvas>
```

I have a simply question - is there any option to add a tooltip on mouseover event on canvas pie arc? Can anyone help me how could i do that.
 I am able to draw a pie chart using canvas please fine the below snippet:

Comment: A canvas needs to be redrawn every time a change is made to it or something needs to disappear. So a tooltip on the canvas requires a redraw. The answer is yes to your simple question.

Comment: Thanks for your comment  @Mouser can you help me out how to add a mouse over  event for each slice do you have any code.

Answer (score 2):

### Canvas.title = "Tool tip text"

At the most basic level you can use the canvas.title property to set the tooltip. Just get the mouse move events and record the mouse position. Then when you detect that the mouse has changed position, check which slice the mouse is over, if any and set the tooltip to match.

Note that the browsers tooltip is a little slow to respond to changes.

#### For a better response.

You could also draw the chart every frame of the render loop and highlight the parts of the pie the mouse is over and create a more responsive tooltip than the browser default which can be a little slow to respond at times.

The example below is just your code with the modification needed to get the basic tooltip.

Note that I keep the mouse event listener and the function that changes the tooltip separate, this is because on some systems the mouse can have a very high sample rate (my current gaming mouse can fire 700+ times a second) and doing too much in the mousemove event can cause laggy response to user input.

```js
    var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
    var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
    var cw = canvas.width;
    var ch = canvas.height;
    ctx.lineWidth = 2;
    ctx.font = '14px verdana';

    var PI2 = Math.PI * 2;
    var myColor = ["Green", "Red", "Blue"];
    var myData = [30, 15, 38, 22, 30, 20, 10];
    var cx = 150;
    var cy = 150;
    var radius = 100;
    var mouse = {x :0,y:0,oldx : 0,oldy:0};

    ctx.globalAlpha = 0.50;
    pieChart(myData, myColor);
    ctx.globalAlpha = 1.00;
    

    function pieChart(data, colors) {
        // calc data total
        var total = 0;
        for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
            total += data[i];
        }
        // calc sweep angles for each piece of pie
        var sweeps = []
        for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
            sweeps.push(data[i] / total * PI2);
            data[i] = {
                value : data[i],
                angle : data[i] / total * PI2,
                text : "Data is "+((data[i] / total) * 100).toFixed(0) + "%",
            }
        }
        // draw outer pie
        var accumAngle = 0;
        for (var i = 0; i < sweeps.length; i++) {
            var f = randomColor();
            drawWedge(radius, accumAngle, accumAngle + sweeps[i], f, data[i].value);
            accumAngle += sweeps[i];
        }

    }

    function drawWedge(radius, startAngle, endAngle, fill, label) {
        // draw the wedge
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.moveTo(cx, cy);
        ctx.arc(cx, cy, radius, startAngle, endAngle, false);
        ctx.closePath();
        ctx.fillStyle = fill;
        ctx.strokeStyle = 'white';
        ctx.fill();
        ctx.stroke();
    }

    function randomColor() {
        return ('#' + (Math.floor(Math.random() * 0x1000000) +
                0x1000000).toString(16).substr(1));
    }
    canvas.addEventListener("mousemove",function(event){
        mouse.x = event.clientX; 
        mouse.y = event.clientY;
    })
    
    function update(){
        // only on change in mouse position
        if(mouse.x !== mouse.oldx || mouse.y !== mouse.oldy){
            var x = mouse.oldx = mouse.x;
            var y = mouse.oldy = mouse.y;
            x -= cx; // vector from pie center
            y -= cy;
            var newText = "My pie chart. Mouse over slices for more info.";
            var dist = Math.sqrt(x * x + y * y); // get distance from center
            if(dist < radius){
                var ang = Math.atan2(y,x); // get angle note y is first
                ang += Math.PI * 2; // rotate 360 as atan2 starts at -Pi
                ang %= Math.PI * 2; // normalize to range 0 to 2Pi
                var i = 0;
                var tAng = 0
                while(i < myData.length-1){
                    if(ang < tAng + myData[i].angle){
                        break;
                    }
                    tAng +=  myData[i].angle;
                    i += 1;
                }
                newText = myData[i].text;
            }
            canvas.title = newText;
        }
        requestAnimationFrame(update);
    }
    update();
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width=512 height=512></canvas>
```